# How to make UIButton shake on tap?

Tags: ios, swift, animation, uibutton, shake

I'm learning about UIView animations using keyframes and spring animations and I'm trying to make a button shake after tapping it. The issue is that I drag and dropped the button from the library and pinned the trailing edge to a UILabel above it and nothing else. In the various examples I see a header constraint but my button has no header. This is the code I have so far

```
@IBAction func noButtonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 1, delay: 1, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.5, initialSpringVelocity: 15, options: [], animations: {
        self.noButtonTrailing.constant = 16
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
    })
}
```

Am I suppose to make a header constraint somewhere? Thanks

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Here is simple media timing animation for linear movement & UIView damping animation.

[image]

*Note: Swift 4*

```
extension UIView {


    // Using CAMediaTimingFunction
    func shake(duration: TimeInterval = 0.5, values: [CGFloat]) {
        let animation = CAKeyframeAnimation(keyPath: "transform.translation.x")

        // Swift 4.2 and above
        animation.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: CAMediaTimingFunctionName.linear)

        // Swift 4.1 and below
        animation.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: kCAMediaTimingFunctionLinear)


        animation.duration = duration // You can set fix duration
        animation.values = values  // You can set fix values here also
        self.layer.add(animation, forKey: "shake")
    }


    // Using SpringWithDamping
    func shake(duration: TimeInterval = 0.5, xValue: CGFloat = 12, yValue: CGFloat = 0) {
        self.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: xValue, y: yValue)
        UIView.animate(withDuration: duration, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.4, initialSpringVelocity: 1.0, options: .curveEaseInOut, animations: {
            self.transform = CGAffineTransform.identity
        }, completion: nil)

    }


    // Using CABasicAnimation
    func shake(duration: TimeInterval = 0.05, shakeCount: Float = 6, xValue: CGFloat = 12, yValue: CGFloat = 0){
        let animation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "position")
        animation.duration = duration
        animation.repeatCount = shakeCount
        animation.autoreverses = true
        animation.fromValue = NSValue(cgPoint: CGPoint(x: self.center.x - xValue, y: self.center.y - yValue))
        animation.toValue = NSValue(cgPoint: CGPoint(x: self.center.x + xValue, y: self.center.y - yValue))
        self.layer.add(animation, forKey: "shake")
    }

}
```

Button Action

```
@IBAction func noButtonPressed(button: UIButton) {

  // for spring damping animation
  //button.shake()  


  // for CAMediaTimingFunction
  button.shake(duration: 0.5, values: [-12.0, 12.0, -12.0, 12.0, -6.0, 6.0, -3.0, 3.0, 0.0])

 // for CABasicAnimation
 //button.shake(shakeCount: 10)  

}
```

Comment: It would be really awesome if you could add a gif too :)

Answer (score 3):

Here is the output for @Krunal code. I used 3 different cases and output is pretty nice :)

[image: Tests]

```
    @IBAction func instagramButtonClicked(_ sender: Any) {
        guard let button = sender as? UIButton else {
            return
        }

        button.shake(duration: 0.5, values: [-12.0, 12.0, -12.0, 12.0, -6.0, 6.0, -3.0, 3.0, 0.0])

    }

    @IBAction func facebookButtonClicked(_ sender: Any) {
        guard let button = sender as? UIButton else {
            return
        }

        button.shake()
    }
    @IBAction func websiteButtonClicked(_ sender: Any) {
        guard let button = sender as? UIButton else {
            return
        }

        button.shake(duration: 0.5, values: [-1.0, 1.0, -6.0, 6.0, -10.0, 10.0, -12.0, 12.0])

    }
```

Comment: Nice.. All are working fine :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for this:

```
let animation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "position")
animation.duration = 0.07
animation.repeatCount = 4
animation.autoreverses = true
animation.fromValue = NSValue(cgPoint: CGPoint(x: self.BUTTON.center.x - 10, y: BUTTON.center.y))
animation.toValue = NSValue(cgPoint: CGPoint(x: BUTTON.center.x + 10, y: BUTTON.center.y))
BUTTON.layer.add(animation, forKey: "position")
```